# How to stop a pointer from updating data from a previous loop?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I am using a for loop to loop though and insert data into a NSMutableDictionary and then inserting that NSMutableDictionary into an NSMutableArray, the code is fairly simple and shown below:

```
for (NSDictionary *selectedOption in selectedOptions) {
     NSString *name = selectedOption[@"name"];
     NSString *value = selectedOption[@"value"];
     [variantRow setObject:name forKey:@"name"];
     [variantRow setObject:value forKey:@"value"];
     [variantInfo addObject:variantRow];
}
```

The problem I am trying to solve is that *name and *value always gets the last value of the loop even for previously inserted dicts into the variantInfo NSMutableArray, I am assuming my problem is because I am inserting pointers etc, but I don't understand how else I can do it? I need to insert the values and have future inserts not affect previous ones.

I hope the description makes sense as its not to easy to explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are modifying the same `NSDictionary` object reference(`variantRow`) in  every iteration and appending it to the array `variantInfo`. You need to create a new NSDictionary object:

```
for (NSDictionary *selectedOption in selectedOptions) {
     NSString *name = selectedOption[@"name"];
     NSString *value = selectedOption[@"value"];
     if(name && value) {
        NSDictionary* newVariantRow = @{"name": name, @"value":value};
        [variantInfo addObject: newVariantRow];
     } 
}
```